# Excel VBA Code to ignore filtered-out (hidden) rows

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have a piece of VB code in excel to hide columns with less than 2 data entries (header as a minimum) and I need to know how to use this to hide columns whilst ignoring information in filtered out rows:

```
Sub HideCols()
Dim LC As Integer, j As Integer
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

LC = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 3 To LC
        Columns(j).Hidden = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(j)) < 2
    Next j


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is what I have, a lot of it makes no sense and needs tidying up but that's only as I've been trying to find my own way to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideCols()
    Dim cols As Range
    Dim iCol As Long

    With Range("Table1")
        Set cols = .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)
        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
             If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) < 2 Then Set cols = Union(cols, .Cells(1, iCol))
        Next iCol
        Set cols = Intersect(.Columns, cols)
        If Not cols Is Nothing Then cols.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

as a side note, if filtering is done out of `Autofilter()` method then also header rows are not filtered out. in this case you may want to change the right term of If check to `< 3`

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's hidden first

```
Sub HideCols()
Dim LC As Integer, j As Integer
Dim LR As Integer, curCnt as Integer
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range
Dim Data As Variant

Set rng = Range("Table1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

LC = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 3 To LC
        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row
        curCnt = 0
        ' its faster to iterate a variant array than it is Cells
        Data = Range( Cells(1, 1), Cells(LR, LC) )
        for k = 1 to LR
           if Rows(k).Hidden = False and Data(k, j) <> "" Then _
           curCnt = curCnt + 1
        next k
        Columns(j).Hidden = curCnt < 2
    Next j


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Also note the line continuation '_' character

Comment: It's still calling the information in the row hidden by autofilter. I need a way to ignore hidden rows not columns.

Comment: Unfortunately we are kind of slow because we look at each Cell 1 by 1, we can increase speed by reading all data into a variant array

Comment: If you can code this, please do. I'm just working as I go and a lot of it could be more efficient. I'd be grateful!

Comment: Are you experiencing poor performance with what we have here?

Comment: It's not great but it's manageable. My concern is those in the business who may use this with older computers.

Comment: Edit Saved. I think you should add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` If you data starts at Row 3 then inside the loop every where there is `k` it should be `k-2` and the data range should be `Range( Cells(3, 1), Cells(LR, LC) )`. If all Rows contain the same number of columns you can put both `LR = ...` and `Data = ...` outside of your `For j` loop